# Can't import NLTK in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, ipython, nltk, jupyter-notebook

I *can* import the nltk package when running python or ipython from bash. So, nltk is definitely installed *somewhere* (in python from bash, 
`nltk.__file__` is
`/home/nadine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.pyc`)

However, when using Jupyter Notebook (which I installed using Anaconda, with the 2.7 version of python), importing nltk fails:

```
import nltk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b06499430ee0> in <module>()
----> 1 import nltk

ImportError: No module named nltk
```

In Jupyter Notebook, `sys.executable` yields `/home/nadine/.conda/envs/py27/bin/python`, while in python from bash it yields `/home/nadine/anaconda2/bin/python2.7`

What exactly is going wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Anaconda uses its own version of Python, and you clearly have installed the `nltk` in the library for system Python.

But Anaconda normally comes bundled with the `nltk`-- why is yours absent? Perhaps you installed a minimal version, and the `nltk` needs to be installed on top of it. Check by running `conda list nltk` at the (anaconda-aware) bash prompt.

Whatever the reason, it sounds like the nltk is not there. Install it with `conda install nltk`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. I resolved it by another jupyter version.

For me it did not work in the classic `juypter notebook`. I installed jupyterlab -> `pip install jupyterlab` and start it with: `jupyter-lab`.

Summary:

```
pip install jupyterlab
jupyter-lab
```

Then it worked!

Comment: After looking into many other SO answers, this one made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, you can try and see which kernel your Jupyter Notebook is running. Perhaps it is not using the [conda root] and therefore doesn't have access to the package.

You should be able to see it in the top-right corner of the Notebook screen. Otherwise go to `Kernel>Change Kernel` in the menu and check there.

Comment: There I can only see that it is running "Python 2". Is there any way of getting more detailed information?

Comment: you can check `help>about` to see which version python your Jupyter Notebook is running. For me it says:

"Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda, Inc.|" for example.

You can also use the `env` command within ipython (where the import works) and jupyter (where it doesn't) to check the details of the environment you are currently in.

Comment: Another way to check the python version you're using is `sys.version` (with `import sys`).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your conda environment is set up with the wrong version of Python. I had this problem and it was resolved by:

- checking the version of python running in the notebook with 
  `sys.version`
- deactivating the current environment
- creating a new environment with that python package
- activating the new environment
- running the notebook, using `import nltk` and `nltk.download()`